# Applescript - set permanent global variable

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I'm new to applescript. I want to create a permanent global variable that I can read and modify later from other applescripts.

I've created a new applescript in script editor, and entered the following code:

```
global myVariable
set myVariable to "text"
```

I ran the applescript by clicking the run button in script editor. The script runs fine. My understanding was that this variable would now be permanent, so running `log myVariable` from a new applescript should return `"text"`.

However, instead I receive the error

```
error "The variable myVariable is not defined." number -2753 from "myVariable"
```

How can I create a permanent variable, permanently stored on my computer and accessible from any applescript?

Additionally, is there a way to log or view all of the global variables that I've created?

Thank you

Comment: A `global` variable doesn't persist, it's just accessible from everywhere in the script. You can save and load a script object including the value to disk, or save the value directly in UserDefaults.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access variables in the other script?  Globals, like properties, are persistent in regular AppleScripts (at least until the script is recompiled).  Issues would be that getting these variables set from the Script Editor can be problematic, and as mentioned, wouldn't really be "permanent" unless using something like the user defaults system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using script objects and properties, if you like. First, create a simple script in Script Editor with the following code:

```
property gvar1 : "a value"
property gvar2 : 27
```

Save it somewhere (e.g.: `/Users/yourname/globalASVariables.scpt`). This file will retain the values you set for the properties.

Now, whenever you want to access these variables in a script, write your code like so:

```
set globalVars to load script "/Users/yourname/globalASVariables.scpt"
log globalVars's gvar1
log globalVars's gvar2
set globalVars's gvar1 to "something"
log globalVars's gvar1
-- this line saves any changes you made to the variables
store script globalVars in "/Users/yourname/globalASVariables.scpt" replacing yes
```

`globalVars` is a script object containing those common properties. They will persist until you recompile the first simple script. You only need to use the `store script` line if you want to change the variables stored in the file.

There might be a way to do this with Script Libraries as well, but I'd need to experiment.